# VBA: cell is not accepted as empty until clicking in

Tags: vba, excel, cells

I'm creating a VBA macro in which I select all empty cells.
It works, but even though some cells are empty, Excel doesn't get they're empty until I double-click in them.

Does anybody know why this is?

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: @SiddharthRout i want to select all empty cells like this: 
inputSheet.Columns("A:D").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select

Comment: That code won't work in the scenario you mentioned which i have described below.

Comment: `xlCellTypeBlanks` property works the same was as `IsBlank`. It returns `True` if the `Cells` are `Empty`. Again, `Empty Cell` is different from `Cell with zero length string`. Although both looks `Empty` visually. What you described above are cells with `Zero length string` which may be a result when you type a formula (eg. ="") and then paste it as `Values`.

Comment: i solved the problem your solution was right and helped me anyway thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

those cells are cells with zero-length strings.
To be able to evaluate them try using `Len` function.

Example:

```
Sub test()

Dim cel, rng As Range, NoVal As Boolean, rngselection As String, i As Long

Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A5")

rngselection = ""
i = 1
For Each cel In rng
    NoVal = IIf(Len(cel.Value) = 0, True, False)
    If NoVal Then
        If i > 1 Then
            rngselection = rngselection & "," & cel.Address
        Else
            rngselection = cel.Address
        End If
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next cel
Range(rngselection).Select

End Sub
```

this selects all empty cells in `Range("A1:A5")`.
Code above is tested and for demonstration purpose only.